# a dynamic milliseconds to time conversion Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to convert milliseconds to time. what I want to do is make it dynamic. for example if the number is just a few seconds or just a few minutes, it would format it with out the leading zeros.

so if the number was, 17604 instead of it being formatted 00:00:17 seconds I would like it to be just 17.

equally if the number was 247268 which is 00:04:07 4 minutes and 7 seconds. I would like it to be 4:07

```
def points_to_time(self, points):
        time = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=points)
        hours, remainder = divmod(time.seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        milliseconds = time.microseconds // 1000
        formatted_time = "{:01}:{:02}:{:02}.{:03}".format(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds // 10)
        return formatted_time
```

I tried if formulas to change the format but I couldn't get it right:

```
formatted_time = ""
    if hours > 0:
        formatted_time += f"{hours}:"
    if minutes > 0 or (hours == 0 and minutes == 0):
        formatted_time += f"{minutes}:" if hours > 0 else f"{minutes}"
    formatted_time += f"{seconds}" if hours == 0 and minutes == 0 else f"{seconds:02}"
    formatted_time += f".{milliseconds:03}"  # Ensure milliseconds are displayed with 3 digits

    return formatted_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.rstrip()` and `.lstrip()` to remove unwanted characters at the beginning at the end of the string:

```py
import datetime

def points_to_time(points):
    dt = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=points)
    h, r = divmod(int(dt.total_seconds()), 3600)  # changed to handle more than a day.
    m, s = divmod(r, 60)
    ms = dt.microseconds // 1000
    # Remove any number of zeroes and colons at either end of
    # the string, and then remove trailing decimal point if alone.
    return f'{h}:{m:02}:{s:02}.{ms:03}'.strip('0:').rstrip('.')

for ex in range(11):
    print(points_to_time(10**ex))
```

Output:

```
.001
.01
.1
1
10
1:40
16:40
2:46:40
27:46:40
277:46:40
2777:46:40
```